# Calling std::abs() with NaN changes floating point control word on x87

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, floating-point, x86, precision

We discovered the following behavior in one of our unit test targets (Windows 32bit, VS2015). When executing the following

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
  unsigned int cw;
  _controlfp_s(&cw, 0, 0);
  printf("before %.04x\n", cw);
  std::abs(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
  _controlfp_s(&cw, 0, 0);
  printf("after %.04x\n", cw);
}
```

the floating point control word changes from `0x9001f` to `0xc001f`. Thus, the precision control is changed from `_PC_53` (53 bits precision) to `_PC_64` (64 bits precision). See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9676k6h.aspx

This in turn triggers different floating point results in our tests. We see this behavior only on 32bit windows systems. Is there anyone who can help make sense of the above behavior? I can not find any documentation on such behavior nor can I find anything in the assembly of `std::abs` that changes the floating point control word.

Comment: No repro.  Can't say I expected one.  Be sure to apply updates, verified with Update 2 installed.  Do keep in mind that VS2015 no longer uses FPU instructions.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the which update we have installed. Have you run this on an x86 or x64 CPU?

Comment: From a C point-of-view (and likely C++) post the result of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  I suspect it is non-zero.  Perhaps compile options can affect that.

Comment: I checked the value of FLT_EVAL_METHOD and it is 0 in case of an error. Also, this happens with VS2015 Update 3.

Comment: We had the same issue. I do not remember the Visual Studio version but it might as well have been 2015. Checked it in 2017 and your program renders two identical control words. In other words, it seems to be fixed.
The strange thing is that I cannot repro it in 2013 nor 2015 both Update 2. Must say I am a bit confused now.